# In Mocha, returning a promise that will be rejected doesn't have the same effect as calling done(err)

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

The mocha docs state

> Alternately, instead of using the done() callback, you may return a
>   Promise. This is useful if the APIs you are testing return promises
>   instead of taking callbacks

But on rejection, these two ways appear to have different results:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

describe('failure', function () {
    describe('why2describes', function () {
        it("fails caught", function (done) {
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                reject(new Error("boom"))
            }).catch(function (err) {
                done(err)
            })
        });

        it("fails return", function (done) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                reject(new Error("boom"))
            })
        });
    })
});
```

The first results in

```
Error: boom
```

The second results in

```
Unhandled rejection Error: boom
```

and then additionally states `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

Am I doing something wrong with the 2nd case?

Comment: Second one doesn't call done which the error message clearly state is the issue, so just call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong with the 2nd case?

Yes. Two things.

1. When you don't have a `catch` handler attached to a Promise chain, the error happens within the chain, will be lost in the form of rejected promise. Bluebird makes sure that nothing like that happens by detecting and throwing that error

   ```
   Unhandled rejection Error: boom
   ```
2. In async case, calling the `done` function is the way let the test processor to know that the current test has completed. In the second case, you never call `done`. So it waits for the default timeout, 2000ms, and then fails the test case with that error.

   But if you like to use the Promises/your API returns a Promise, then you should not use `done` function at all. Your code should look like this

   ```
   it("fails return", function () { // no `done` argument here
       return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           // ideally you would be doing all the assertions here
       })
   });
   ```

   The other important thing to note when dealing with Promises based testing is, you should return the promise object.

Comment: what is the better way when using bluebird? to use done() or to use the promises like your code above?

Comment: @TalAvissar If your API already returns a Promise, I would recommend the code above.